# What is the optimal way to fitting a rectangle around a set of integer squares?

Tags: geometry, optimization, area

Suppose we are given a set of consecutive integer squares, of sides $1, 2, 3 ... n$ . Our task is to find the rectangle of least area which can fit around these squares.

For instance, when $n=3$, we can fit the squares into a $3*5$ rectangle, which means only 1 unit of area inside the rectangle is vacant.

[image]

When $n=4$, a $5*7$ rectangle is required, which involves 5 units of area wasted.

[image]

It becomes progressively harder to solve as $n$ increases. Below is the data for what I believe to be the solutions up to $n=8$

$$
\begin{array}{c|cc}
n & \text{Rectangle} & \text{Wasted area} \\
\hline
1 & 1*1 & 0  \\
2 & 2*3 & 1 \\
3 & 3*5 & 1 \\
4 & 5*7 & 5 \\
5 & 5*12 & 5 \\
6 & 9*11 & 8 \\
7 & 11*14 & 14 \\
8 & 14*15 & 6
\end{array}
$$

$n=8$ seems to be an outlier against the general trend of a larger area being wasted as $n$ increases. This is a nifty solution:

[image]

So my questions is: Is there a general algorithm for choosing the dimensions of the optimal rectangle and how the squares should be packed into it?

Bonus question: what if we generalised to the 3rd dimension: stacking cubes in a cuboid?

Comment: Never underestimate OEIS: https://oeis.org/A081287

Comment: Also, [A038666](https://oeis.org/A038666)

Comment: wow remarkable. thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

This wasn't put into an answer, so I guess I'll just leave it here:

> R. K. Guy, Unsolved Problems in Geometry, Section D4, has information about several related problems

This is an unsolved problem in mathematics. Here are the sequences in the OEIS:

https://oeis.org/A081287
https://oeis.org/A038666